# Daihatsu Charade 1993 Starting Problem

Tags: engine, cold-start, daihatsu

I drive an old Charade 93', when I try to start it in cold, the engine doesn't start with high rpms, it starts at very low rpms and its difficult to rev it up the first minute; I have to start the engine 2 or 3 times before I can drive. Someone can help me? Any guesses?

Comment: To start, engines need fuel, ignition, compression, and power. I am guessing power so check your battery first.

Comment: @findwindow The battery has just been able to start the engine 3 times, it can’t be in too bad condition.

Comment: I would first check that the engine temperature sensor is working.

Comment: @HandyHowie yes at first I thought it was the temperature sensor, so I changed it for a new one, and didn't work :(

Comment: What maintenance was performed (plugs, oil, etc)? Has fuel pressure been checked?

Comment: @FDryer I've checked and changed the plugs and oil, but I haven't check the fuel pressure yet